# ASP.NET Page Fragment

Tags: asp.net

In my requirement I need to add or remove a sub-page or page-fragment (or similar component, I don't know the name, similar to User Control) dynamically.

The page-fragment can contains other controls like menu or button or textbox.

I have a dropdown menu. Depending on the selection of that menu I will add a fragment with textbox or a fragment with dropdown menu. There will be an option to remove any added fragment.

But I don't know what asp.net component will be handful to achieve this!

Any information will be very helpful. I am not using MVC.

---

Edit:

Well, this is similar to the Wicket Fragment. I didn't find any online demo, but found this [blog](http://pawelzubkiewicz.blogspot.in/2009/06/wicket-swapping-replacing-fragments.html), this might be useful to clarify my requirement.

Comment: You had it correct when you said "user control", though for ASP.net its just a "web user control".

Comment: @Kadajski is there any similar things? It is hard to maintain the keep track of user control.

Comment: Well from what I understand of your question you're asking what web control is similar to a User Control, and the answer is that a 'web user control' is the same thing just the web equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more information will help. But assuming a little bit, I think you can do any of the following,

1. Add controls using JQuery, handle the dropdown index change event and add code to display the textbox/dropdown.
2. You can make a usercontrol with textbox/dropdown and add it to page controls whenever the dropdown changes.
3. You can use a composite control and show/hide it accordingly. Composite controls are a little more complicated to write but can be distributed across projects while user controls can be used only in given projects.

For 2/3, put the new user control in a partial update control, handle dropdown's selected index change event at server side and update it's visibility according to your requirements.

First approach is recommended since it's done at client side and gives better user experience but it does need a little efforts.

Thanks!

Comment: Well depending on what he wants the jQuery way may not be best as controls added by jQuery would be hard to get access to from the server as they wouldn't be a part of the viewstate. I think the webforms way of doing this would be to use an update panel and then set the dropdown to autopostback and change the control to different web user controls based on the selection in the dropdown.

Comment: Using Jquery should not be difficult, nor do any access from server is needed. A server side webservice or page function can provide the data for dropdown. Hidden values with viewstate turned on can hold the information from these new fields.